# error occurred while installing pycharm on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

[image]i am using ubuntu 14.04 and  pycharm professional edition i tried to install but getting this type of error

```
               aused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class git4idea.GitVcs overrides final method getName.()Ljava/lang/String;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:195)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:191)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:167)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.b(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.a(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:66)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.b(ActionManagerImpl.java:561)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:927)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:224)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
```

this is the current java version  running on my ubuntu

```
      creator@creator:~$ java -version
      java version "1.8.0_05"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
      Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Please check your version of Java. I use pyCharm with Ubuntu 14 and it runs well. It looks like your pyCharm installation is conflicting with your java installation. You might have OpenJDK installed, if you do then change it to Oracle's java and you might solve your problem.

Comment: name@name:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Does this happen every time you start them up?  Could you download a newer version of either IDE and try to start them up?  How about a newer version of Java?

Comment: did you have a previously installed pycharm? could you clean previous setting, installation folder and so on then? Also, can you show us full error log?

Comment: yes i have previously installed pycharm from past 15 months it's working fine but after installing some library it's stop working and showing me some error like this